# How do you speed up System.Diagnostics.Process execution?

Tags: asp.net

The code behind of an ASP.NET program calls an executable that prints a one-page order report.  The executable is called as follows:

```
Process.Start( "PrintOrder.exe", nOrderNumber.ToString());
```

But when user clicks on the Submit there a considerable slow-down (if I comment the above line, the execution is very fast).

Is there a way to speed up the Process?

Answer (score 1):

It would be a nice idea to perform an exact measurement to see if it's OS process start code is slow or whether there are other impediments.

If it's OS-related, not really much can be done without making structural changes to the code behavior. Of the options that come into my mind:

- Make operation asynchronous (fire-and-forget style, just run the process in the background) - works only if you don't need the result of it's execution;
- Make "PrintOrder.exe" always running and receiving requests via WCF named pipes channel or whatsoever.

Comment: Dmitriy, thank you for your message.   I know that when I execute the PrintOrder.exe at the command prompt, not from the ASP.NET app, it runs very fast. 
As far as making the operation asynchronous, I do not need the result of the execution.  How do you make the operation asynchronous?  Is it something that is done on the ASP.NET side or on the PrintOrder.exe side?

Comment: @Hidalgo Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process.Start( "PrintOrder.exe",  nOrderNumber.ToString()));

Comment: Thank you, Dmitriy.   I will follow your suggestion.